# Unable to compile project with cmake - undefined reference to `ns_initparse'

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, g++, linker-errors

i can compile project with pure g++ command, but i can't do same with cmake. Sorry for dumb question. I just start to work with cmake and google won't give me any solutions.

**This is working fine**

```
g++ -static main.cpp -o test -Wl,-Bstatic -lresolv -lutil -lstdc++
```

But when i compile with cmake i receive such errors

```
undefined reference to `ns_initparse'
undefined reference to `ns_parserr'
undefined reference to `forkpty'
```

**My cmake file**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_link_options("-static")
add_compile_options("-lresolv -lutil") #it's like this options won't set
add_executable(test Source/main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try linking additional libs with target_link_libraries. Defining sources per target is also fancy:

```
add_executable(test)

target_sources(test
    PRIVATE
    Source/main.cpp
    )

target_link_libraries(test
    PRIVATE
    -lresolv
    -lutil
    )

target_compile_options(test
    PRIVATE
    -Wl
    )
```